# Vectorize matching values between 2 dataframe columns in R

Tags: r, vectorization

This seems quite elementary so I apologize if this question has been answered. I'm self taught and may lack the correct vocabulary to locate an answer.

I want to enter the values in one column of a dataframe (let's call it df1) into multiple rows of another dataframe (df2). They will be matched by another Id column.

So, for example,

df1 would be

```
   Id   didAThing
    1   TRUE
    2   TRUE
    3   FALSE
    4   FALSE
    5   TRUE
```

df2 is

```
Id  didAThing
1   NA
1   NA
1   NA
2   NA
2   NA
2   NA
3   NA
3   NA
3   NA
4   NA
4   NA
4   NA
5   NA
5   NA
5   NA
```

and final output would be

```
Id  didAThing
1   TRUE
1   TRUE
1   TRUE
2   TRUE
2   TRUE
2   TRUE
3   FALSE
3   FALSE
3   FALSE
4   FALSE
4   FALSE
4   FALSE
5   TRUE
5   TRUE
5   TRUE
```

I've created a working example of a solution using looping below. I'd like to be able to vectorize this because my actual data-set is very large.

```
df1<-data.frame("Id"=c(rep(1:5)),"didAThing"=c(T,T,F,F,T))
df2<-data.frame("Id"=c(rep(1:5,each=3)),"didAThing"=NA)

for (i in 1:NROW(df2)) {
  df2[i,2]<-df1[df2[i,1],2]
  }
```

It is possible that NAs will show up in the Id numbers as well, so it would be great if the solution didn't break in that case. Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer!

*edit 
Thanks for the fast responses. I realize that I left out the important detail that these columns are part of a much larger data frame, so ideally I'd like to just modify the one column if possible.

Comment: Seems tha you could use `match`; something like `df2$didAThing = df1$didAThing[match(df2$Id, df1$Id)]`

Comment: @alexis_laz, that seems like the most succinct and direct answer. My thanks. If you made that an answer, I would vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df2[,-2,drop=F],df1, by="Id")
#    Id didAThing
#1   1        TRUE
#2   1        TRUE
#3   1        TRUE
#4   2        TRUE
#5   2        TRUE
#6   2        TRUE
#7   3       FALSE
#8   3       FALSE
#9   3       FALSE
#10  4       FALSE
#11  4       FALSE
#12  4       FALSE
#13  5        TRUE
#14  5        TRUE
#15  5        TRUE
```

Or   using `data.table`

```
 DT1 <- data.table(df1, key="Id")
 DT2 <- data.table(df2[,-2,drop=F], key="Id")
 DT2[DT1]
```

---

Another way using `data.table`:

```
 DT1 <- data.table(df1)
 DT2 <- data.table(df2, key="Id")
 DT2[DT1, didAThing := i.didAThing]
```

This *updates* `DT2`'s `didAThing` column alone, and *by reference*, and therefore should be fast and memory efficient. The `i.didAthing` is a shortcut to refer to `DT1's` `didAThing` column... And since you say you've huge data.frames (without mentioning the actual size), you can use `setDT` to convert the data.frames to data.tables by reference. That is;

```
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
setkey(df2, Id)
df2[df1, didAThing := i.didAThing]
```